# Memory access of VM's

Tags: ram

I am new here. I am doing my research project on Memory access features of VM's.
I wanted to know how can I see the memory access of VM's till page level. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 as a VM and I have installed this one on the Ubuntu Server 14 version.
Could anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, below the link, anyone should use wss.pl script.

https://github.com/brendangregg/wss.

It worked for me.